# Changing the color of directories and files in my shell (ZSH)

Tags: shell, colors, zsh

I have tried a few quick hacks online but nothing has worked so far. Basically I've just install ZSH after using windows linux subsystem and I want to change the annoying color of files/directories.

Here's how it looks currently:

[image]

[image]

I'd like them to have **no** green background.

Thanks!

Comment: This is controlled by `ls`, not `zsh`. Consult the documentation for your version of `ls`.

Comment: http://linux-sxs.org/housekeeping/lscolors.html, https://askubuntu.com/questions/466198/how-do-i-change-the-color-for-directories-with-ls-in-the-console